# How can I partition a PostgreSQL table using part of a character field?

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

PostgreSQL 11.4

Table foo contains a field my_datetime character varying(254)

I want to partition foo using this field, but only the year, month, day portion of the string
value `20200328175432`

`Substr(my_datetime,0,9)` gives me `20200328` <- that's the value I want to use as my "partition key"

Since its a charcater field I assumed I needed to do something like `to_date(substr(my_datetime),'YYYYMMDD')` to get it cast to a date
so my partition definition looks like this:

```
partition by range to_date(substr(datetime,0,9), 'YYYYMMDD');
```

but that doesn't work.

So do I have to go old school and create an on insert trigger to move my data around (foo yuck - about 100,000 rows every 5 minutes)

I can't change the table field definitions, I might be able to add fields, but I'd have to add a trigger to populate them - right?

Creating the partition tables isn't what I'm asking - assume I have every day of the year for the next 5 years created like 20200328_foo

Anyone have a suggestion? Something else I can try?

Comment: Why are you storing a `timestamp` in a `varchar` column. That is a **really**, really bad idea. If it was proper `timestamp` that partitioning on it would be easy. "*Something else I can try*" - yes, choose the correct data type for your data. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=885172825a4ee5987d651242152f925e

Comment: I can't change that column type (yea that would be the "easy" button). Its the way the COTS vendor created it and allows in-gestation of timestamps to the minute, second and fraction of a second. If I change it their software breaks.

Comment: That wouldn't give me much trust in that vendor if they can't even get the most basic design stuff right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a function to overcome the questionable (not to say stupid) design decision of that software vendor:

```
create function fix_broken_type(p_input text)
  returns date
as
$$
  select to_date(p_input, 'yyyymmddhh24miss');
$$
language sql
immutable; --<<< this is important
```

Then you can use that function for the partition definition:

```
CREATE TABLE data
(
   want_to_be_timestamp varchar
)
partition by range (fix_broken_type(want_to_be_timestamp));
```

And then add the partitions:

```
create table data_2020_01_01 partition of data
  for values from ('2020-01-01') TO ('2020-01-02');
```

Of course this will fail miserably if a value is inserted that can't be converted using `to_date()` that way.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=1d570d404332766896f1f7959a1ab647)

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to up-vote this for now - I'm still figuring out how to make the partition work for just one day and not the whole month